# FFMPEG map 7.1 surround to 5.1 during transcode

Tags: video, ffmpeg, aac, transcode

I have a ProRes MOV whose audio contains 8 channels of audio in a 7.1 surround layout (L R C LFE Ls Rs Lt RT).

I am preparing an H.264 MP4 for a media player that only supports AAC, and does not support 7.1, so I would like to map to 5.1, dropping ther 7th and 8th channels (Lt and Rt). Under normal circumstances I would just use the below for my transcode:

ffmpeg -i input_file  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryslow -crf 18 -c:a aac output_file

I've been looking at the [documentation for audio layout manipulation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation), but am having trouble wrapping my head around it and they don't have a specific example of what I'm trying to do.

Do I need to export my audio to a WAV file first, or is there a way to manage the mapping in my transcode command? How can I map the existing first 6 channels to the new file?

Comment: [This one](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a5.1stereo) is most relevant to what you're doing. Just specify the number of channels `-ac 6` to downmix.

Comment: @kesh downmixing doesn't work for me as it will impact the overall mix and separation of channels – really just need to drop them completely

Comment: Then use the `pan` filter as the linked section suggests (right below the `-ac` example)